# 二重forについて

Tags: php

どなたかお力添えをお願いいたします。
原因は内側のfor文だと思うのですが、二重for文のコードが上手く書けません。

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j + 1 <= $i; $j++) {
        echo "*";
    }

    for ($k = $i + 1; $k <= 5; $k++) {
        echo $k - $i;
    }
    for ($l = 3; $l >= $i; $l--) {←これが間違っている
        echo $l;
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

↑の結果
1234321
*12332
**123
***1
```

出したい結果↓
1234321
*12321
**121
***1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

折り返しの開始が3固定になっています。また`$l`が1未満になったときループを終了すればよいと思います。

```php
for ($l = 3; $l >= $i; $l--) {←これが間違っている
    echo $l;
}
```

を

```php
for ($l = 4 - $i; $l >= 1; $l--) {
    echo $l;
}
```

とすればよいと思います。※動作確認はしていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。正解です。どうやってそういう発想になるのですか？初期値を変えることには目が注目していませんでした。

Comment: 回答者ではありませんが出したい結果に着目すると、  
`321`
`21`
`1`
のようにパターン化できます。
初期値が`3`-`2`-`1`と変わっているので、そこに着目してfor文を書きます。

Comment: なるほど。教えてくれてありがとうございます。

Comment: 質問のコードの出力結果は1行目が期待どおり3から始まり、2行目以降も3から始まっていましたので、for文の初期処理を見てみました。予想どおり3固定となっていましたので誤りに気付きました。スタック・オーバーフローでは回答横のチェックマークを押すことで回答を承認することもできますので、よろしければ承認をお願いします。

Comment: 承認しました。スタック・オーバーフローは使ってこなかったので勝手が分からず、すみませんでした。最後に教えてくれてありがとうございました！